# How can I print my object values(attributes)?

Tags: angular, undefined

model:

```
     export interface People {
       count: number,
       next: string,
       previous: any,
       results: {
          name: string;
          height: string;
          mass: string;
          hair_color: string;
          skin_color: string;
          eye_color: string;
          birth_year: string;
          gender: string;
          homeworld: string;
          films: string[];
          species: string[];
          vehicles: string[];
          starships: string[];
          created: Date;
          edited: Date;
          url: string;
        }
      }
```

service:

```
     export class StarwarsService {

     private url: string = "https://api.codetabs.com/v1/proxy?quest=https://swapi.co/api/";
     result: Array<any> = [];

     constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

     getByContent(route: string): Observable<any> {
     for(let i = 1; i < 87; i++) {
     this.result.push(this.http.get<{people: People[]}>(`${this.url}${route}/?page=${i}`));

     }
     }
```

component:

```
        export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
        people: People[] = [];

        constructor(private starWarsServ: StarwarsService) { }


        ngOnInit() {
          try {
            this.starWarsServ.getByContent(`${this.route}`)
            .subscribe(data => {
              {console.log(data['results']); this.people = data['results'].name;}
            })


          catch(err) {
            throw err;
          }
          }
```

I am trying to print data[].results.name, but it always return undefined.

I set my objects as same as the API.

I have tried a lot of things, but I cannot print.
I am sorry if this is an easy task, but I just started programming...
thank you!

....................................

Comment: try consoling data['results'] and display the result in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Andre, http.client not work as you think. httpClient.get return an Observable (not a result) and you received the data in a subscribe. So, first you getByContent must be return an observable.

In only has an observable you simple

```
getByContent(route: string,page:number): Observable<any[]> {
     return this.result.push(this.http.get(`${this.url}${route}/?page=${page}`));
}
```

In you need make several independents calls you need use forkJoin

```
   result: Array<any> = [];
   getByContent(route: string,page:number): Observable<any[]> {
     for(let i = 1; i < 87; i++)
        this.result.push(this.http.get(`${this.url}${route}/?page=${i}`));

     return forkJoin(this.result) //<---return forkJoin
   }
```

forkJoin return an array with so many elements your array of observables (in your case 86)

NOTE: make a console.log(data) to know what data you received

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this one    
 getByContent(route: string,page:number): Observable<any[]> {


   for(let i = 1; i < 87; i++)
        this.result.push(this.http.get<any>(`${this.url}${route}/?page=${i}`));

     return forkJoin(this.result); 
       }


In compo
this.starWarsServ.getByContent(`${this.route}`)
            .subscribe(data => {
            for (item in data )
console.log(item.name)
            });
```